# How to work with JSON nested objects

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api

I have this Json derived from another json array:

> {"location":"La Gravière - Officiel","name":"Conférence de presse
>   Animatou 2015 et soirée à la
>   Gravière!","start_time":"2015-09-17T18:00:00+0200","timezone":"Europe/Zurich","id":"1632156500365990"}
>
> {"location":"Université de Safrania","name":"Conférence \"Pokémon's
>   Studies\"","start_time":"2015-10-31T20:30:00+0100","timezone":"Europe/Paris","id":"372932366218217"}
>
> {"location":"Digital October Center","name":"BigData
>   Conference","start_time":"2015-09-18T09:00:00+0300","timezone":"Europe/Moscow","id":"680056618762120"}
>
> {"location":"Centro Cultural de Belém","name":"iMed Conference 7.0® –
>   Lisbon 2015","start_time":"2015-09-17","timezone":"Europe/Lisbon","id":"700462560065856"}
>   {"location":"Universiteit
>   van Amsterdam / Oudemanhuispoort","name":"2015 Amsterdam Regional
>   Conference","start_time":"2015-09-19","timezone":"Europe/Amsterdam","id":"1608898599391019"}

This is the result of the following code:

```
            string searchKeyword = "conference";
            Facebook.JsonObject result = (Facebook.JsonObject) fbClient.Get("/search?q=" + searchKeyword + "&type=event");
            JsonArray data = (JsonArray)result["data"];
            for(int i = 0; i< data.Count; i++)
            {
                JsonObject l = (JsonObject) data.ElementAt(i);
                Response.Write(l);
            }
```

When I try to get the location of every conference in the jsonobject, I get the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

I use this code to get the locations:

```
        for(int i = 0; i< data.Count; i++)
        {
            JsonObject l = (JsonObject) data.ElementAt(i);
            Response.Write(l["location"]);
        }
```

What is the proper way to easily work with this data? I have tried to first deserialize the data object but this gives an error.

If I execute this code:

```
            string searchKeyword = "conference+reggae";
            Facebook.JsonObject result = (Facebook.JsonObject) fbClient.Get("/search?q=" + searchKeyword + "&type=event");
            JsonArray data = (JsonArray)result["data"];
            Array d = data.ToArray();
            Response.Write(result);
```

I get this output:

```
{"data":[{"end_time":"2015-09-26T06:00:00+0200","location":"Blue Note Düsseldorf","name":"DANCEHALL CONFERENCE 2 YEARS ANNIVERSARY / EARDRUM SOUND & CHANTA CREW / Dancehall, Mashup, Reggae, HipHop","start_time":"2015-09-25T23:00:00+0200","timezone":"Europe/Berlin","id":"1001780686562929"},{"location":"Blue Note Düsseldorf","name":"DANCEHALL CONFERENCE lgs. EARDRUM SOUND / Dancehall, Mashup, Reggae, HipHop","start_time":"2015-10-23T23:00:00+0200","timezone":"Europe/Berlin","id":"1639387246339755"}],"paging":{"cursors":{"before":"MAZDZD","after":"MQZDZD"}}}
```

How would I proceed to get every location of every entry?

For now I have solved it by using a try-catch clause around the response.write, it seems the gotten JSON wasn't consistent.

Code:

```
            for (int i = 0; i < data.Count; i++)
            {
                JsonObject l = (JsonObject)data.ElementAt(i);
                try
                {
                    Response.Write(l["location"]);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }

            }
```

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting that error, but that isn't valid json, its not an array

Comment: I have edited the question with additional info (variable dump of "result")

Answer (score 0):

I would like to strongly suggest, go through the "newton json" library. I found it very useful for working with json data. You will find examples by little rnd. It's easy and provide very clean code to do operations with json.

Comment: [link](https://jsonclassgenerator.codeplex.com/)

Please use this link in case of you have json structure is fix. this tool will generate class from json